# "desire that" + subjunctive?

Tags: subjunctives

If I want Leonard to eat a banana, is this a desire that Leonard *eat* a banana or a desire that Leonard *eats* a banana? How about a desire that my best friend *like* me / my best friend *likes* me? Would using the subjunctive in the second case suggest that this is a counterfactual desire?

Comment: Don't say *I desire that Leonard eats / [should] eat a banana* anyway. It's not very natural English. Just say *I **want** Leonard **to eat** a banana*. But if you *must* use the subjunctive form (which I recommend you to avoid wherever possible), it's probably usually best to explicitly precede it by ***should***. The choice of subjunctive (with or without ***should***) instead of a finite verb form like ***eats*** has absolutely no connection to "degree of improbability" or counterfactuality

Comment: ...so obviously it's *I **want** my best friend **to like** me*. If you go around saying things like *I desire that my best friend likes / [should] like me,* you'll be lucky to have any native Anglophone friends at all! It's just too *weird!*

Comment: Thanks! So, while unnatural, the second form would be the correct one?

Comment: If you have to pass an exam, use the subjunctive *(**eat**).* And *if possible* include ***should*** before it, but if you're faced with one of those tiresome "multiple choice" questions where you can only choose between ***eat*** and ***eats*** (from some ignorant test-setter who thinks **I desire that Leonard XXX a banana** is a sensible utterance with only those choices), you *must* choose subjunctive ***eat***. But myself, I'd rather look for a better test-setter!

Answer (score 1):

The subjunctive in English is optional. Hence

> I desire that he eat a banana

and

> I desire that he eats a banana

are both correct.  And both are non-idiomatic.

It is much more idiomatic to say "I want my friend to eat a banana" or "I want my friend to like me."

You might use the subjunctive in highly formal situations.  These are exceptionally rare and most learners will never be in a situation in which the subjunctive is the best choice.

> His Majesty the King desires that he be taken from this place.